# JSF tag not rendered after navigation

Tags: java, jsf, tags, navigation

I am actually trying to do a web application using JSF, and I have some issue with the rendering in the web browser.

Here is the context :

I have an index.xhtml page which displays correctly the JSF tags, and I want to navigate to another through a simple hyperlink.

```
<h:outputLink  value="/Advisor/AddClient.xhtml">
       <h:outputText value="Add a client" />   </h:outputLink>
```

But then, the AddClient page doesn't displays the result of the JSF tags as it should.

Here is the addclient file :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"      
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!-- a validation script used in py page -->
        </script>


        <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{loginBean.isLogged}">
            <h:form id="formu" onsubmit="return validation()">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            First name :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtFName" value="#{clientCreationBean.fname}"/>                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Last name :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtLName" value="#{clientCreationBean.lname}"/>                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            E-Mail :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtEmail" value="#{clientCreationBean.email}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Address :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             <h:inputText id="txtAddress" value="#{clientCreationBean.address}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Zip code :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtZip" value="#{clientCreationBean.zip}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            City :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtCity" value="#{clientCreationBean.city}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Phone :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtPhone" value="#{clientCreationBean.phone}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <h:commandButton action="#{clientCreationBean.CreateClient()}" value="Ajouter"/>
            </h:form>
          </h:panelGroup>



    </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

and here is my web.xml :

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>   
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Any idea of why the JSF is not interpreted in my others pages?

**UPDATE :**

I got AddClient to work like this :

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Moving AddClient.xhtml to the same folder than Index.xhtml (and not in the "Advisor" folder anymore), and changing my link to :

```
<h:outputLink  value="AddClient.xhtml">
    <h:outputText value="Ajouter un client" />
 </h:outputLink>
```

But when I let the page in the Advisor folder with a link poiting at /Advisor/AddClient.xhtml, it doesn't work. why?

Thanks,

KiTe

Comment: please show your add client file

Comment: post updated :)
the whole html code can be get in the browser, but jsf tags are not interpreted

Comment: first of all i would like to suggest you that since you are using JSF then why u r still living in d old world by using `tr` and `td` for creating table, u can use inbuilt tags to display a table using JSF

Comment: I am going from an old version to a JSF version, it is planned to do so. But still, getting it interpreted first seems to be a good starting point ^^

Comment: @KiTe : Your first problem is url pattern in faces servlet mapping as MattHandy mentioned in his answer.
After that, you are using a template in add client page. While using  template you have to use ui:define tags on the page, you havent used it anywhere. I think you need to solve both the problems

Comment: the template page works well, since my index page uses it and is well displayed.
I think the problem comes from the mapping, but whatever I put there, I get different issues .. and that's why I'm asking for some help here :s I'm a newbie with JSF ^^'

Comment: @KiTe have you tried `<url-pattern>*jsf</url-pattern>` with `value="/Advisor/AddClient.jsf"` ?

Comment: @KiTe get the point man. I was not saying that problem is in template page. The problem is in addclient page. Where you use template, you have to use ui:define tags for overriding the content in template. You haven't used ui:define tags in your addclient page

Comment: <ui:define name="XXX"> must be set when you explicitly give a "name" to <ui:insert>.
If you create a unique <ui:insert>, without a name, it will automatically display the content of the whole <ui:composition> instead.
Anyway, I added the <ui:define> and explicitly set a name to my <ui:insert> to be sure my problem didn't come from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link doesn't match the faces servlet mapping:

```
<h:outputLink  value="/Advisor/AddClient.xhtml">
```

will not match the pattern:

```
/faces/*
```

That's why the FacesServlet will not be invoked and your JSF tags are not processed.

You can either change the link to:

```
<h:outputLink  value="/faces/Advisor/AddClient.xhtml">
```

or better use the .xhtml suffix mapping to in your *web.xml*:

```xml
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I already tried these two before posting here, but it didn't work

Comment: with the first one i get a 404 exception, with the second either a "java.io.FileNotFoundException" or a "/Advisor/faces/AddClient.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource" depending on what I put in my link

Comment: Is `Advisor` the context root or a folder in your web page direcotry?

Comment: Ok, my bad. Changed the outputlink for the `/faces/*` mapping; `value="/faces/Advisor/AddClient.xhtml"`.

Comment: I still get a 404 or java.IO.exception .. kinda weird. well for now I'll keep working with the modifications I did in the last edit since it seems to work. I'll try to apply your advices in a new project later, to figure out why it didn't work. thanks